# VBA Evaluate Index Match

Tags: vba, excel

I have done a fair bit of searching and can't find an answer for this specific case.

My data set is ~650k lines long so I have been trying to make the code as quick as possible.
What I am trying to do is get VBA to index match an entire column with another sheet.

So far my code is VB:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).Value = Evaluate("INDEX(MATCH(C2:C" & LastRow & ",'CC Map'!A:A,0),0)")
```

This very quickly compares column C to sheet 'CC Map'!A:A; and puts the value in column Q.
However, I want to return the corresponding value from 'CC Map'!B:B

When I use
VB:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).Value = Evaluate("INDEX('CC Map'!B:B,MATCH(C2:C" & LastRow & ",'CC Map'!A:A,0))")
```

It returns every value the same (corresponding to match C2...)

I think the issue is with having an array as the second argument in INDEX, but I am trying to avoid loops.
What I have at the moment runs almost instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the return values are text, you could use:

```
Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).Value = Evaluate("INDEX(IF(1,T(OFFSET('CC Map'!B1,MATCH(C2:C" & LastRow & ",'CC Map'!A:A,0)-1,0))),)")
```

For numeric values, replace T with N.

Comment: That worked great, ran it over 653k rows in 3.882 seconds. There are few things I can improve with that code. Really appreciated.